# How to access an image in a different folder?

Tags: java, image, embedded-resource

How would I access a picture in a different folder in Java? I have a series of pictures and they change based on user input, which is what `x` is for.

```
picture.setIcon(new ImageIcon("\\resources\\icons\\pictures\\"+x+".png"));
```

The images are located (from the .class files) in resources/icons/pictures, but the above code doesn't work. The value of `x` isn't the problem since it works as it should. Am I calling the pictures the right way?

Comment: pictures are in classpath / some where else from file system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I calling the pictures the right way?

Probably not.  If they are (embedded) application resources they will typically be in a Jar and unavailable via the `String` based constructor of the `ImageIcon` (which expects the `String` equates to a `File` path).

For an embedded resources, access them by `URL`.

```
URL urlToImg = this.getClass().
    getResource("/resources/icons/pictures/"+x+".png");
picture.setIcon(new ImageIcon(urlToImg));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using forward slashes instead of backslashes I believe.

```
new ImageIcon("/resources/icons/pictures/"+x+".png")
```

This is the standard Java cross-platform way of denoting resource file paths. It still works on Windows - the Java runtime library handles the transaltion for you.

Answer (score 0):

> The images are located (from the .class files) in resources/icons/pictures

That's a problem. The system isn't interested in where the class file is, but from where you invoke a program.

Specifying a resource folder via command line,

```
java -jar myJar.jar C:\\home\\of\\the\\images
```

or via a property

```
java -jar myJar.jar -DImageHome=/foo/bar/images
```

or from a properties file is most flexible.

If you like to put the images into the jar, use Andrews suggestion, getClass ().getRessource ("...");

Btw: I know for sure, that forward slashes are portable. Backslashes, afaik, aren't.